# shell script pattern matching?

Tags: regex, shell, ftp, scripting

I think I've written maybe one shell script my entire life, and I'm not even sure if it's possible to do this, but I'm trying to write a script that will ftp the contents of a directory, one at a time.  That is, it'll ftp one and then close the connection, then ftp the second, and close that etc.  This is because there may be up to five files in a directory all of which are a minimum of 2GB each.  FTPing them all at once always results in a reset connection.  I thought that if I could match by partial filename, then perhaps that will help, as they are all named the same way.

So, in a directory, it'll have:

```
SampleFileA_20100322_1.txt
SampleFileA_20100322_2.txt
SampleFileB_20100322_1.txt
SampleFileC_20100322_1.txt
```

I'd like to ftp SampleFileA_xxxx_1 first, then SampleFileA_xxxx_2, etc.  This is the current ftp script, which tries to download everything all at once...

```
#!/bin/bash
REMOTE='ftp.EXAMPLE.com'
USER='USERNAME'
PASSWORD='PASSWORD'
FTPLOG='/tmp/ftplog'
date >> $FTPLOG

ftp -in $REMOTE <<EOF
_FTP>>$FTPLOG
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWORD
bin
cd download
mget *
quit
_FTP
:wq!
```

Comment: `mget *` ought to be getting the files sequentially, not simultaneously.  When is the connection being reset?  (e.g., immediately? in the middle of the first file? after the first file? later?)

Comment: if your connection resets, it has something to do with your network settings. sometimes if you have firewalls in between, the firewall may have such timeouts enabled. Or sometimes its because of tcp timeout settings with your kernet etc..

Answer (score 1):

based on your question I think you need something like

```
files=`ls Sample*txt`

for file in $files
do
  run_ftp_function $file
done
```

you'll need to setup "run_ftp_function" to do the send (like you already have) using $1 as the file to send